# Turn off Time Machine notifications (Ventura)

Tags: time-machine, notifications, system-settings, ventura

I keep getting the "No Backups for X Days" notification on my Mac from Time Machine. System Preferences layout was updated for Ventura, so the old answers on how to turn off the notifications don't work anymore. Has anyone found an updated solution?

Edit: the proposed duplicated question doesn't answer my question. The duplicated question and answer is specifically for pre-Ventura. In my question title and description, I mentioned that this is for Ventura.

Comment: The accepted answer includes Ventura steps as well